# Dlookup passing incorrect value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using DLookup

```
Dim FormName As String
Dim OldBBusinessterm As Long
Dim field As Long
Dim NewBusinessTerm As String
Dim NewRecord As DAO.Database
Dim rstUpdate As DAO.Recordset

oldbusinessterm = Me!BusinessTermID.OldValue 'equal 5194 in test
NewBusinessTerm = Me!BusinessTermID.Value     ' equal 5195 in test

BusinessTerm = DLookup("[businesstermdesc]", "tblbusinessterm", "  [businesstermid] =" & oldbusinessterm)

' here is the issue - [businesstermid] = 5195 - it should be setting the  value from Oldbusinessterm but it is populating it from New businessterm

Set NewRecord = CurrentDb
Set rstUpdate = NewRecord.OpenRecordset("TblFieldTermLink")

   rstUpdate.AddNew
   rstUpdate("GTSBusinessTerm").Value = BusinessTerm
   rstUpdate("BusinessTermID").Value = Me!BusinessTermID.Value
     rstUpdate.Update
```

My problem is that it is reading the businesstermID from my open form, instead of doing the dlookup using the old value.

Any ideas as to why

Comment: The OldValue will only contain the original database value while the current form record is not saved.  But a form will automatically save the current record on certain focus changes, etc.  You have comments that the values are different "in test", but how did you test?  It might work one time as you expect if you trace through the code, but other times it might fail if for any reason if the form navigation causes the record to be saved prior to the code running.  You also don't say where/when this code runs?  Is it in a form event?

Comment: Add a `debug.print` statement right before you do the `DLookup` and I bet you will be surprised at the result: `Debug.Print Now(), "Showing Business Term Description for Business Term ID " & oldbusinessterm`

Comment: I run the code on the BEFORE UPDATE of the form.

Comment: Debug Print shows the correct value
`2017/11/01 07:16:05 AM Showing Business Term Description for Business Term ID 5914`
My old value shows 5914 - which is correct
My new value is 5915 - Which is correct
My dlookup is showing the businestermdesc as My new Value
My dlookup is showing my oldbusinessterm as correct value as correct

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a new record to table `TblFieldTermLink` you are using the new BusinessTermID value. If you want the Old value you should modify your code to reflect that:

```
   rstUpdate.AddNew
   rstUpdate("GTSBusinessTerm").Value = BusinessTerm 'String Text describing old BusinessTermID
   rstUpdate("BusinessTermID").Value = oldbusinessterm 'Long Value of old BusinessTermID
   rstUpdate.Update
```

I also notice that you are not using the variable you declared to hold the old business term id:

```
Dim OldBBusinessterm As Long
oldbusinessterm = Me!BusinessTermID.OldValue 'equal 5194 in test
```

Notice the spelling of the two. Which is why capitalization did not follow. Perhaps you want to correct the `Dim` statement:

```
Dim OldBusinessTerm As Long
```